# Existence of a Second Order Linear Homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Does there exist a second order Linear Homogeneous ODE such that $ u=x^2$ and $v=x|x|$ are their solutions? What about $ u=x$ and $v=|x|$  ?

All I know is that these two functions are Linearly Independent on $\mathbb R$ and their wronskian vanishes on R.

I don't know how to find such an equation. Any hints will be appreciated.